# Button Not Making Activity Launch

Tags: java, android

Right now I am getting a force close on my android emulator.

Upon finishing this app, I will want to put a custom field in instead of just test, but for now I just want test to show up from the http activity.

Any help would be great!

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

public final static String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "com.example.main.MESSAGE";


/*@SuppressLint("ParserError")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}*/

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

private Button searchBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
    super.onCreate(savedInstance);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    searchBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(null, http.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}   
}
```

Http:

```
public class http extends Activity {

public http(){
    httpMethod();
}


public void httpMethod(){
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://api.site.com/api/");

    try {
        // Add your data
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
       ;

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        String test = "hello";

        TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
        myTextView.setText(test);

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    }
}    
 }
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name="com.example.main.DisplayMessageActivity"/>
    <activity android:name="com.example.main.http"/>
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3):

There are whole lot of issues in the code:

1)  `Intent intent = new Intent(null, http.class);`

Use first parameter as MainActivity.class instead of null

2)  httpActivity should have `onCreate` (or) `onResume` life cycle activity methods to create activity for `startActivity`

Not but the least, please spend some time on reading documentation and doing example programs instead of just type-in something and post on SO. By going through all your questions it is something like SO community did your app for you.

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize `Intent` like this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, http.class);
```

You need to pass `Context` as first parameter not *null*.

Comment: test still didn't display once I clicked the button

Comment: you need to check if your second activity has set Content and overrided onCreate method.

Answer (score 1):

start as:

```
searchBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, http.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

instead of passing `null` as First parameter in Intent Constructor

for more information see here

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: That fixed the force close... but "test" still didn't display

Answer (score 0):

I trully advice you to read some Android basics beacause you have some issues in the code:

1. You have a *null* context when you're initializing the intent at the button's listener. You should have: `Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), http.class);` or `Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, http.class);`
2. You need to create your ativity and set it's content. You must override at least the *onCreate* method.
3. It's not so important, but its a good practice to write code that anyone might understand instead of write code for the machine! I'm telling this because you have *activity_main* sml file where you define your main activity layout and menu. I suggest you to refractor these file names to something like *main.xml*, for the layout, and *main_mnu.xml*.